Do Affluence Boons increase money recieved from NPCs?
Affluence type Boons received from Chaos make it so any Gold Crowns you find are worth more. Does this boost apply to Gold earned from NPCs like Poseidon's Sunken Treasure Boon or Narcissus's Precious Metals gift?


It does count for it. Any Affluence boon of Chaos will end up giving you this Gold Crown modifier which will affect the formula for Gold Crown obtained no matter the source, that being:

Finishing an encounter
Encounters rewarding Gold Crown
Beaking golden urns
Arachne's "Moonlight Dress"
Medea's "Wealth from the Dead"

And as you asked, gold directly received from NPCs, such as:

Echo's "Reward Reward Reward",
Hermes "Quick Buck"
Narcissus "Precious Metals"
Poseidon "Sunken Treasure"
Winning a wager battle against Nemesis

